# Recommended VLF File Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the recommended VLF File Count for 120 GB size database in SQL Server?

I appreciate anyone response quickly .

Thanks,

Govarthanan

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and 2014(Standard Edition)

Comment: VLF related auto grow rules changed with SQL server 2014.

Comment: What about 2012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many excellent articles on managing VLFs in SQL server; but the crux of all of them is- **It depends on you!**

Some people may need really quick recovery, and allocating a large VLF upfront is better.

**DB size and VLFs are not really correlated.**

You may have a small DB and may be doing large amount of updates. Imagine a DB storing daily stock values. It deletes all data every night and inserts new data in tables every day! This will really create a large log data but may not impact mdf file size.

Here's an [**`article`**](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/important-change-vlf-creation-algorithm-sql-server-2014/) about VLF auto growth settings. Quoting important section

> Up to 2014, the algorithm for how many VLFs you get when you create, grow, or auto-grow the log is based on the size in question:
>
> - Less than 1 MB, complicated, ignore this case.
> - Up to 64 MB: 4 new VLFs, each roughly 1/4 the size of the growth
> - 64 MB to 1 GB: 8 new VLFs, each roughly 1/8 the size of the growth
> - More than 1 GB: 16 new VLFs, each roughly 1/16 the size of the growth
>
> So if you created your log at 1 GB and it auto-grew in chunks of 512 MB to 200 GB, you’d have 8 + ((200 – 1) x 2 x 8) = 3192 VLFs. (8 VLFs from the initial creation, then 200 – 1 = 199 GB of growth at 512 MB per auto-grow = 398 auto-growths, each producing 8 VLFs.)

IMHO 3000+ VLFs is not a big number but alarming. Since you have some idea about your DB size; and assuming you know that typically your logs are approximately n times your DB size.

Then you can put in right auto growth settings to keep your VLFs in a range you are comfortable with.

I personally will be comfortable with a setting of 10 GB start with 5 GB auto-growth.

So for 120 GB of logs (n=1) this will give me 16 + 22*16=368 VLFs.
And if my logs go up to 500 GB, then I'll have 16+ 98*16=1584 VLFs